# Display nib above of my storyboard view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to essentially load a nib into view when a certain criteria is met. I'm able to show the nib on my storyboard thought I cant seem to be able to execute any actions when the button is pressed.
Just to express my ultimate goal. I would like to create sort of a template with my nib view and then display the nib view from my storyboards but manipulate the labels in my nib view with values sent from the storyboard.
OK so I'll do my best to try and show my detail steps on how i try to accomplish this.
Firstly here are is a picture of my project.

[image]

my VCDemoView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

VCDemoView.m

```
#import "VCDemoView.h"
@interface VCDemoView ()
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *subtitleLabel;
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *container;
//- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender;

@end




@implementation VCDemoView



-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self == nil) return nil;
    [self initalizeSubviews];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self == nil) return nil;
    [self initalizeSubviews];
    return self;
}

-(void)initalizeSubviews
{
    //Load the contents of the nib
    NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    //Add the view loaded from the nib into self.
    [self addSubview:self.container];
}




- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {


    //[self.subtitleLabel.text = @"MIGUEL"];
    _subtitleLabel.text = @"miguel";


}
@end
```

storyboard view controller.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "VCDemoView.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    VCDemoView * CustomView = [[VCDemoView alloc]init] ;//[[addMyLocation alloc]init];


    [self.view addSubview:CustomView];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I cant seem to be able to communicate with the button? I'm sure is something silly.
here is a link to the dropbox  project with all the source code if you prefer to see it that way.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/23cbhs4qvsxwei0/AADFs6MN3eqJNK42Io2etuJea?dl=0
Thanks is advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the frame of your `VCDemoView`.  The frame defaults to `CGRectZero`.

A view doesn't clip its subviews by default, so you can still see the labels and the button, even though they're outside the bounds of the `VCDemoView`.  But a view does not receive events outside its bounds, so when you tap on the button, the top-level view swallows the event because it finds that the event is outside the bounds of its one subview (the `VCDemoView`).

You can fix the frame of your `VCDemoView` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    VCDemoView * CustomView = [[VCDemoView alloc]init] ;//[[addMyLocation alloc]init];
    CustomView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    CustomView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Note that you can use autoresizing even though your storyboard uses autolayout constraints.  Autolayout will turn the autoresizing mask into constraints for you.

Or you could just put your `VCDemoView` in your storyboard as a child of the root view and set up the constraints there.

Comment: this was confusing because eventhough I was not setting the size I was still able to see it on my viewcontroller. Just one more question if you dont mind. How do i change the height of the nib to maybe like 50% of the parent?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to change.

Comment: I basically just want to set the height and width to a percentage smaller than that of the storyboard, for lack of a better term I will be reciclying this view to be used from several storyboards but I like to change it dimensions, so as to not take the entire view width and Height. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need to add constraints in your xib because right now the labels and the button don't have any.  If you set the `VCDemoView`'s frame to something smaller than the xib size, you'll run into the same problem you started with.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call and action inside a *View* this what the *Controller* should handle . 
You need to change the fileOwner to be the controller and the View Class to be *VCDemoView* , connect the View to the controller in the IB , and load the nib from there , then add it as a subView to the ViewController's view .

this the edited code ,, I hope it helps .. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33359624/demo-SO/Archive.zip

Answer (score 1):

You are not set the **CustomView** frame so the default frame is CGRectZero. if you set the frame of the CustomView it will works fine.

```
 @implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    VCDemoView * CustomView = [[VCDemoView alloc]init] ;
    CustomView.frame =self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:CustomView];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```